# Obligatory sequence of rules in CFG

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to write a CFG that starts with 10 and ends with 10 {0,1}.
But I have noticed that for it to work the rules I have written must be followed in a special sequence.
Let me show you with an example.

```
S -> 10S Rule 1
S -> S10 Rule 2
S -> 1S Rule 3
S -> 0S Rule 4
S -> ε Rule 5

Rule 1 -> 10S -> Rule 2 -> 10S10 -> Rule 3 101S10 -> Rule 4 -> 1010S10 -> Rule 5 101010
```

Here I would end up perfectly starting with 10 and ending with 10, but this is only if the Rule 1 is first in the sequence and Rule 2 is also taken into account before closing it down with Rule 5 ending up having 101010.

Is this the right way to write this CFG in? I mean let's say someone starts of with:

```
Rule 1 -> 10S Rule 3 -> 10S1 -> Rule 4 -> 10S01 -> Rule 5 -> 1001.
Now my CFG doesn't hold up because I expected the Rule 2 to be involved to get the string to end with 10.
```

Should I expect my CFG to work no matter what rule is taken first or last? Is that the only "legit" way of writing a CFG? And if it's like mine is now (dependent on a particular sequence taken) it is considered to be faulty?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help, I appreciate it.